# New-QADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'proxyAddresses'

Tags: powershell

I created a script for bulk user creation in AD and it works correctly:

```
Import-CSV C:\Users\NewUsers.csv | 
ForEach-Object { 
    New-QADUser -Name $_.Name -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -Office $_.Office -Title $_.Title -Description $_.Description -Department $_.Department -Company $_.Company  -City $_.City -StateOrProvince $_.State -UserPassword $_.UserPassword -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -ParentContainer $_.ParentContainer -mail $_.mail -manager $_.manager 
}
```

But I want another thing.
Apart from creating a user with those parameters I want to also get the following:

- proxyAddresses
- targetAddress
- extensionAttribute1
- extensionAttribute3

But when running the script adding those parameters it gives me an error:

```
Import-CSV C:\Users\NewUsers.csv | 
ForEach-Object { 
  New-QADUser -Name $_.Name -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -Office $_.Office -Title $_.Title -Description $_.Description -Department $_.Department -Company $_.Company  -City $_.City -StateOrProvince $_.State -UserPassword $_.UserPassword -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -ParentContainer $_.ParentContainer -mail $_.mail -manager $_.manager -proxyAddresses $_.proxyAddresses -targetAddress $_.targetAddress -extensionAttribute1$_. extensionAttribute1 -extensionAttribute3 $_.extensionAttribute3
}
```

The error is:

> [PS] C:\Users\Prueba>.\NewUsers.ps1 New-QADUser : A parameter cannot
>   be found that matches parameter name 'proxyAddresses'. At
>   C:\Users\Prueba\NewUsers.ps1:1 char:505
>   + ... ger $*.manager -proxyAddresses $*.proxyAddresses -targetAddress $_.targetAddress ...
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-QADUser], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Powershell.Cmdlets.NewUserCmdlet

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks from your error like there is no specific ProxyAddresses parameter switch, there isn't one for the native PS New-AdUser command either, but this works:

```
New-AdUser -Name $name -OtherSettings @{
    'proxyAddresses' = $myproxyaddresses
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Scepticalist, you solved my problem!!

Comment: You can mark this as the answer if the problem is solved